# Rails sitemap_generator by kjvarga doesn't run because of legacy ACL Trying to set access that already has uniform-bucket-level-access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-storage, sitemap-generator-gem

I'm trying to use rails sitemap_generator. The Gem can be found here. https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/
I'm getting the error

```
rake aborted!
Google::Cloud::InvalidArgumentError: invalid: Cannot insert legacy ACL for an object when uniform bucket-level access is enabled. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access.
```

The adapter's code is [here](https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/blob/4c381d53a17b6edf289c90b3527fd95dcd063d1a/lib/sitemap_generator/adapters/google_storage_adapter.rb#L34) I've high lighted the line that sets acl to public.

This is how I initialized it

```
SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.adapter = SitemapGenerator::GoogleStorageAdapter.new(
  credentials: JSON.parse(ENV['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']),
  project_id: 'homeoncall',
  bucket: 'homeoncall.com'
)
```

Is there another option I can pass when I initialize that doesn't try to set the acl policy. I can always change the bucket's policy on Google Cloud Platform but thats not the access policy I want to use. I appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you all.

Comment: nope :( 
I just ended up using that access policy.